# java threads different streams

Tags: java, multithreading

this code reads numbers from different steam data , and outputs the whole sum. is there something wrong with this code ? how can i fix it ?

```
public class Thr extends Thread{
static int numThr=100, sum=0;
private int num;
private Thr(int num){this.num =num;}
public void run() {
    int k = IntegerReader.get(num);
    int count=0;
    while(k>0) {
        if(count%numThr==num) sum+=k;
        count++;
        k=IntegerReader.get(num);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
    thr[] st =new thr[numThr];
    for(int i=0; i<numThr; i++) st[i] = new Thr(i);
    for(int i=0; i<numThr; i++) st[i].start();
    System.out.println("sum = "+sum);
}
}
```

Comment: `'is there something wrong with this'` isn't really the type of question we answer here.

Comment: Why do you think there's something wrong with this code? What doesn't work as expected? What is `IntegerReader`?

Comment: `There is something wrong with my car, how can I fix it?`

Comment: There are lots of things wrong with this code from a stylistic perspective.  Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: This question would be better for codereview.stackechange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous things wrong right off the bat.

1. Sum is being shared between multiple threads and incremented in multiple threads meaning that you can get inconsistent values since incrementing a value isn't an atomic operation.

   The easiest fix for this is change the declaration of sum to: 
     `private static AtomicInteger sum = new AtomicInteger(0);`

   and add to it this way:
     `sum.getAndAdd(k)`
2. "numThr" is shared between multiple threads and read by multiple threads.  Since numThr is   not final, synchronized or volatile there isn't any guarantee that other threads will see that its value has been initialized.  numThr should be declared as `private static final int numThr=100`
3. Your `System.out.println("sum = "+sum);` is going to be printed before your threads have finished executing.  You need to "join" on your threads (that is, wait for them to complete) before printing sum.  Add: `for(int i=0; i<numThr; i++) st[i].join();` before your sysout.

I think you should read up on the Java Memory Model and concurrency in Java.
Here is a basic tutorial, but you really need a book on the subject:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: i am a bit out of practice with java.. why not declare sum as `volatile` ?

Comment: It can't be plain volatile since he is incrementing the variable and there are three operations happening when sum is incremented.  One problematic scenario could be: Thread 1 reads sum (sum=0) and is then preempted by Thread 2.  Thread 2 reads sum (sum=0), increments and writes sum (sum=1).  Thread 1 resumes, increments the value it read for sum (0) and then writes sum (sum=1).

Comment: @MikeMike if you find his answer helpful you should accept his answer. welcome to stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several things wrong with this code. One way to fix it would be by taking the time to read and understand a [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). Another way would be to ask someone else to fix it for you, but be warned that kind of thing won't be taken well around here.